# Empty vars when calling method from singleton class

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

So I have a singleton class in which I have implemented the delegate of my module. However when that delegate method gets executed in this singleton I call a method in another class of the App and it crashes because all the variables previously set in that class are empty.

```
class Player: Jukebox, JukeboxDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = Player()

    func setDelegate(){
        jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self)
    }

    func play(Link: String) {
        jukebox.setIT([JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string: Link)!)])
        jukebox.setImage(currentImage)
        jukebox?.play()
    }

    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: Jukebox, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if pltype == PlayerType.Playlist {
            MyMusicVC.continuePlaying() { () -> () in
            }

        }
    }

    func jukeboxStateDidChange(state: Jukebox) {

    }


    func jukeboxPlaybackProgressDidChange(jukebox: Jukebox) {

    }

    func jukeboxDidLoadItem(jukebox: Jukebox, item: JukeboxItem) {

    }

    func jukeboxDidUpdateMetadata(jukebox: Jukebox, forItem: JukeboxItem) {

    }
}
```

Any ideas on why could this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its hard to understand what is going on. But you are subclassing a Jukebox class. Then making this subclass a delegate of the Jukebox itself. Then I also notice you're setting a Jukebox property that appears to be optional but not.

For example. Why in the play() function is jukebox. used twice but the last line is jukebox?. Is jukebox optional? Or implicitly unwrapped? And if thats the case, why are you using it unwrapped twice and then optionally the third time.

Have you tried not making this singleton a subclass of jukebox. Instead just make it conform to the JukeBoxDelegate protocol and see if that accomplishes the same goal?

Comment: I´ve just done that and everything continues to be the same. It works but when my method gets called all variables are empty. :(

Comment: Which method is getting called and which variables are empty? Are they all properties of the superclass?

Comment: I am calling the method continuePlaying() which is a method of a VC. And the variables that are empty are properties of that VC. I´m going to try with a NSNotifications instead.

Comment: Yeah. it might be helpful to show paste in the code you're talking about. (the view controller properties and methods related to this jukebox)

Comment: I was able to fix it using a NSNotification to call the variable. But anyway thank you very much for your time and effort that you have put into trying to fix my issue :)